# Combine two columns into a third column as a list in R

Tags: r, list

Suppose I have data frame in R

```
A B
d test1
e test2
```

Suppose I want to combine two columns A B to a new column C which is list of columns A and B

```
A B     C
d test1 (d,test1)
e test2 (e,test2)
```

Comment: `df$C <- apply(df, 1, list)` ?

Comment: Use function `paste0`

Answer (score 0):

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = c("d","e"),
  B = c("test1", "test2"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Solution:

`apply` the function `paste0` to rows (`1`) in `df`, collapsing them by `,`and assign the result to `df$C`:

```
df$C <- apply(df,1, paste0, collapse = ",")
```

Result:

```
df
  A     B       C
1 d test1 d,test1
2 e test2 e,test2
```